# ag-grid-n2 causing Can't resolve all parameters for my editor component

Tags: angularjs, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I'm declaring a few editorFrameWork components for my ag-grid in my Angular 2 project. However, when I inject any services in the constructor of my editor component, TypeScript compiler throws the following error upon loading the webpage:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MyOtherEditorFrameworkComponent: (?)
  at CompileMetadataResolver.getDependenciesMetadata (http://<rooturl here>/main.bundle.js:39398:19)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getTypeMetadata (http://<rooturl here>/main.bundle.js:39299:26)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getDirectiveMetadata (http://<rooturl here>/main.bundle.js:39074:28)
    at http://<rooturl here>/main.bundle.js:39167:49
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://<rooturl here>/main.bundle.js:39161:49)
    at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (http://<rooturl here>/main.bundle.js:57492:47)
    at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://<rooturl here>/main.bundle.js:57430:37)
    at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://<rooturl here>/main.bundle.js:57421:21)
    at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://<rooturl here>/main.bundle.js:41293:25)
```

I've gotten around this problem for another editor component that required a service injected, by declaring a module for the component and including the module in app.module. However, this doesn't seem to work for the second editor component, if I add the second editor component module similarly defined below in app.module along with the first editor component module.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MyOtherEditorFrameworkComponent} from './my-other-editor-framework.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [MyOtherEditorFrameworkComponent]
})
export class MyOtherEditorFrameworkModule{ }
```

**src/app/components/.../mySecondEditorFrameworkComponent/my-second-editor-framework-component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { AgEditorComponent } from 'ag-grid-ng2/main';
import { MyInjectedService } from '../../../services/myinjectedservice/my-injected.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-name-editor',
  templateUrl: './name-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./name-editor.component.sass']
})
export class mySecondEditorFrameworkComponent implements OnInit, AgEditorComponent {
@ViewChild('mySecondEditor', { read: ViewContainerRef }) mySecondEditor;
constructor(private myInjectedService : MyInjectedService ) { }
 ...}
```

**src/app/app.module**:

```
@NgModule({ 
    imports: [
        AgGridModule.withNg2ComponentSupport(),
        MyOtherEditorFrameworkModule,
        //MySecondEditorFrameworkModule, //<-- this throws the error
        ...],
     ...
     providers: [ myInjectedService]
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

Component `mySecondEditorFrameworkComponent` is not a module, it should be placed in `declarations` instead of `imports`.

Comment: That's what I had meant the first time, it was a typo. This is still causing the error

Comment: It looks like you have to move `myInjectedService` to separate module and import into app module and MyOtherEditorFrameworkModule module.

Comment: import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MyInjectedService } from './myinjected.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [MyInjectedService ]
})
export class MyInjectedService { }